# How do i fix Blackberry App submission compatibility?

Tags: android, blackberry, compatibility

When submitting an Android app to the Blackberry App World for compatibility, it says my app uses features that are not compatible with current version of Blackberry Runtime for Android Apps. What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

There is quite the [list of unsupported features](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/apisupport) on Blackberry's site.

If they won't give you more details on what you're using that's unsupported, that list is a good starting point.

There are also [some downloadable tools](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/tool) that can help you verify things locally and possibly give you more details on what's wrong.